# Python EXIF extraction gives error with Android photos

Tags: android, python, base64, exif

I am trying to extract the EXIF metadata information from an image sent to the Google Cloud as a base64 string from a phone with this code:

```
imgdata = base64.b64decode(str(base64_string)) 
image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(imgdata))
for orientation in ExifTags.TAGS.keys() : 
    if ExifTags.TAGS[orientation]=='Orientation': 
        break 
exif=dict(image._getexif().items())
```

Although the above code seems to work for IOS, it crashes with Android photos giving `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'items'` on the last line:

```
exif=dict(image._getexif().items())
```

I know that I can check if `._getexif()` is `None` or not before trying to access it, but why do you think this error is happening? Is it related to how Android stores the EXIF information? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible the image simply doesn't have EXIF information? Have you verified with another tool that it does? Is it possible to share a sample image with us?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who might be struggling for the same reason, I couldn't get `_getexif()` working with Android images whether it had EXIF information or not. Instead, we passed the EXIF information to backend directly from the frontend.

I also noticed that the EXIF dictionary of iPhone taken images had the orientation variables in key `'274'` whereas in Android taken images the key was `'Orientation'`.